# Magento 2: impossible logout

Tags: magento2

Magento 2.2.5

When I click to logout button then get error:

```
{"0":"Notice: Undefined index: form_key in \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mydomain.com\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/module-customer\/Model\/Plugin\/CustomerFlushFormKey.php on line 48","1":"#0 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mydomain.com\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/module-customer\/Model\/Plugin\/CustomerFlushFormKey.php(48): Magento\\Framework\\App\\ErrorHandler->handler(8, 'Undefined index...', '\/home\/fsg\/domai...', 48, Array)\n#1 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mydomain.com\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\\Customer\\Model\\Plugin\\CustomerFlushFormKey->aroundExecute(Object(Magento\\PageCache\\Observer\\FlushFormKey\\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Observer))\n#2 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mydomain.com\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\PageCache\\Observer\\FlushFormKey\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Observer))\n#3 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mydomain.com\/public_html\/generated\/code\/Magento\/PageCache\/Observer\/FlushFormKey\/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\\PageCache\\Observer\\FlushFormKey\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('execute', Array, NULL)\n#4 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mydomain.com\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Event\/Invoker\/InvokerDefault.php(72): Magento\\PageCache\\Observer\\FlushFormKey\\Interceptor->execute(Object(Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Observer))\n#5 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mydomain.com\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Event\/Invoker\/InvokerDefault.php(60): Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Invoker\\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod(Object(Magento\\PageCache\\Observer\\FlushFormKey\\Interceptor), Object(Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Observer))\n#6 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mydomain.com\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Event\/Manager.php(66): Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Invoker\\InvokerDefault->dispatch(Array, Object(Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Observer))\n#7 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mydomain.com\/public_html\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/Event\/Manager\/Proxy.php(95): Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Manager->dispatch('customer_logout', Array)\n#8 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mydomain.com\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/module-customer\/Model\/Session.php(467): Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Manager\\Proxy->dispatch('customer_logout', Array)\n#9 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mydomain.com\/public_html\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Customer\/Model\/Session\/Interceptor.php(258): Magento\\Customer\\Model\\Session->logout()\n#10 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mydomain.com\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/module-customer\/Controller\/Account\/Logout.php(80): Magento\\Customer\\Model\\Session\\Interceptor->logout()\n#11 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mydomain.com\/public_html\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Customer\/Controller\/Account\/Logout\/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\\Customer\\Controller\\Account\\Logout->execute()\n#12 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mydomain.com\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Action\/Action.php(107): Magento\\Customer\\Controller\\Account\\Logout\\Interceptor->execute()\n#13 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mydomain.com\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Action\\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#14 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mydomain.com\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\Customer\\Controller\\Account\\Logout\\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)\n#15 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mydomain.com\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Customer\\Controller\\Account\\Logout\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#16 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mydomain.com\/public_html\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Customer\/Controller\/Account\/Logout\/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\\Customer\\Controller\\Account\\Logout\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)\n#17 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mydomain.com\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/FrontController.php(55): Magento\\Customer\\Controller\\Account\\Logout\\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#18 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mydomain.com\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#19 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mydomain.com\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)\n#20 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mydomain.com\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/module-store\/App\/FrontController\/Plugin\/RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#21 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mydomain.com\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\\Store\\App\\FrontController\\Plugin\\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#22 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mydomain.com\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/module-page-cache\/Model\/App\/FrontController\/BuiltinPlugin.php(73): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#23 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mydomain.com\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\\PageCache\\Model\\App\\FrontController\\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#24 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mydomain.com\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#25 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mydomain.com\/public_html\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/FrontController\/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)\n#26 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mydomain.com\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Http.php(135): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#27 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mydomain.com\/public_html\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/Http\/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch()\n#28 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mydomain.com\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->launch()\n#29 \/home\/fsg\/domains\/mydomain.com\/public_html\/index.php(39): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor))\n#30 {main}","url":"\/customer\/account\/logout\/","script_name":"\/index.php"}
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an error in magento 2
It's resolved in this PR:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/16386/files/90e37b59cce7e07a4aee3a5bbc9a00b10aaa58a6

If you want fix this bug in your project you can override the plugin 
vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Plugin/CustomerFlushFormKey.php 
and change the condition in line 48 to

```
if (isset($beforeParams['form_key']) && $beforeParams['form_key'] === $currentFormKey) {
```